# Why does a decrease in entropy cause a rejectection of thermal energy (specifically with relation to caloric materials)?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am currently looking at the caloric effects e.g magneto, elasto, electro for a sixth form research essay project (17 years old). From what I understand, in some of the cases when the entropy of a system **decreases**, energy is released in the form of thermal energy. For example, when  the domains of a magnet align and the dipoles in electrocaloric materials align, the materials heat up. But what I am confused about is how when Nitinol changes from the austenitic to martensitic phase, which is an **increase in entropy**, the temperature also **increases**. Now while there have been many useful articles on here about this phenomenon - especially hysteresis in rubber bands, I'm failing to understand why the decrease in entropy causes heat to be rejected in some cases but not others. Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, and most importantly, we recall that the Second Law tells us that entropy can't be destroyed.

Entropy is the thermodynamic [conjugate variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) to temperature; thus, it's the "stuff" that temperature changes tend to shift. (Compare volume, the conjugate variable to pressure; pressure differences tend to shift volumes, as when a system is driven to expand or contract, for example.) **Thus, one way to change a system's entropy is to heat or cool it.**

Entropy can also be stored in various modes, such as thermal, configurational, electronic, and magnetic modes; these are different ways to express various possibilities for the constituent particles, such as motion, position, or bonding arrangement. One can sometimes force a shift from one mode to another, as when one stretches or releases an elastomer* or allows or forces a phase change from one crystal structure to another. The austenite structure has a higher entropy than the martensite structure—the higher-temperature equilibrium phase is always the higher-entropy phase—so when the former transforms into the latter, **entropy associated with the structure is transformed into thermal entropy associated with a higher temperature.**

Does this resolve your multiple findings?

*The classic example is to stretch a rubber band, let it sit for a few seconds to equilibrate with the surrounding temperature, and then allow it to relax while touching it to one's lips—a very sensitive bio-thermometer. The relaxation increases the configurational entropy because the once-straightened polymer chains can now assume a variety of kinked arrangements. This entropy has to come from somewhere, and it's ultimately taken from the thermal entropy, thus cooling the material. One has effectively produced a solid-state refrigerator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I still do not fully understand what you are saying about the austenite structure - does it not have lower entropy since it has a more regular lattice arrangement? I was under the impression that when the nitinol changed from the martensistic to austenitic phase, that is when it heats up. Have I understood this incorrectly? Thanks again.

Comment: The reason that one crystal structure has a larger entropy than another is often not easily explained. It's the subject of active research on the various configurational, electronic, and magnetic effects. Your comment about temperature changes says the opposite of your question. Please link any source material you're referring to.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I meant to write in my comment 'austenitic to martensitic. Thank you for letting me know about the active research. I have never studied thermodynamics at school so what I understand is from the internet and textbooks. So in summary, when one component of entropy increases, another decreases to compensate; and in an adiabatic process (?) this is the thermal entropy. With SMAs, the Aus-Mart transformation means a decrease in 'lattice' entropy so an increase in thermal entropy? Can you explain what you mean by 'entropy is released' please. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: The total entropy remains approximately constant if the transition is sufficiently gradual, so if the new structure has a lower entropy, the entropy has to go into another mode: the thermal mode. I reworded that section in case "release" is misleading.

Comment: When you say about the transition being sufficiently gradual - if I bend the nitinol wire (which I have lying around at home) quickly, it is hotter than if I bend it slowly over the period of a few seconds. Is this because the total thermal energy released is the same (assuming all other factors are kept constant apart from time) but is released over a longer period of time so the temp change is less noticeable? Perhaps it is to do with how you define 'sufficiently gradual'

Comment: Fast processes generate more total entropy, which complicates the issue; it's simpler to assume the ideal case in which no entropy is generated (reversibility) so that only entropy transfers need to be considered.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time, help and patience. I really appreciate it.